# How to solve the "errno 121 Duplicate key on write or update"?

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I need to pull values from the table x_world with attributes

```
 CREATE TABLE x_world(
    id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
    x INTEGER NOT NULL,
    y INTEGER NOT NULL,
    tid INTEGER NOT NULL,
    vid INTEGER NOT NULL,
    village VARCHAR(100),
    pid INTEGER NOT NULL,
    player VARCHAR(100),
    aid INTEGER NOT NULL,
    alliance VARCHAR(100),
    population INTEGER
);
```

When deriving a table called "igralec" from the x_world table I get a "duplicate key error" but I don't understand how when my keys are primary and unique.
This is my CREATE TABLE script where the error shows

```
    CREATE TABLE pleme (
    tid INTEGER UNIQUE PRIMARY KEY,
    tribe VARCHAR(100))DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_slovenian_ci;
INSERT INTO pleme VALUES (1,"Rimljani");
INSERT INTO pleme VALUES (2,"Tevtoni");
INSERT INTO pleme VALUES (3,"Galci");
INSERT INTO pleme VALUES (4,"Narava");
INSERT INTO pleme VALUES (5,"Natarji");
INSERT INTO pleme VALUES (6,"Huni");
INSERT INTO pleme VALUES (7,"Egipcani");

CREATE TABLE aliansa (
    aid INTEGER UNIQUE PRIMARY KEY,
    alliance VARCHAR(100))DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_slovenian_ci AS SELECT DISTINCT aid,alliance 
    FROM x_world;

DELETE FROM aliansa WHERE aid = 0;

CREATE TABLE igralec (
    pid INTEGER UNIQUE PRIMARY KEY,
    player VARCHAR(100),
    tid INTEGER NOT NULL,
    aid INTEGER NOT NULL,
    FOREIGN KEY (tid) REFERENCES pleme(tid),
    FOREIGN KEY (aid) REFERENCES aliansa(aid))DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_slovenian_ci AS
    SELECT DISTINCT pid, player, tid, aid FROM x_world;
```

So here I am referencing the "tid" from "pleme" and "aid" from "aliansa".
To answer the question "Are there for sure no duplicate values in x_world?" No there are not and that is 100%.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vcxDi.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qdFXO.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sY2aF.png)

Comment: Show **complete and unchanged** error message - the tale about it is not enough.

Comment: I have attached a picture. It is in the image description.

Comment: Distinct does not provide the uniqueness of one separate column. If 2 rows with the same  `pid` but different `player`, `tid` and/or `aid` exists then tho different rows with the same `pid` should be inserted which will cause duplicate error. *I have attached a picture. It is in the image description.* Look it carefully and ensure that the rest of the message is not shown.

Comment: I understand that, but I know there are no rows with 2 same pid values. I will attach another image. I hope i understood you correctly. Thank you.

Comment: Also, this code works for other people but not for me. It might be a bug but I can not think of a way to solve it.

Comment: Does `SELECT pid FROM x_world GROUP BY pid HAVING COUNT(1)>1;` gives empty output?

Comment: Try to divide your query. Firstly execute CREATE TABLE only then INSERT .. SELECT - if 2nd query fails the error message will show duplicated `pid` value.

Comment: I have added the output of SELECT pid FROM x_world GROUP BY pid HAVING COUNT(1)>1; in the post (first image link)

Comment: As I have said, "If 2 rows with the same pid but different player, tid and/or aid exists then tho different rows with the same pid should be inserted which will cause duplicate error". Check rows with found values in source table.